# Accessing file path in the os

Tags: python, file, file-io, operating-system

The following line, unless I'm mistaken, will grab the absolute path to your directory so you can access files

`PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))`

This is what I've been using typically access files in my current directory when I need to use images etc in the programs i've been writing.

Now, say I do the following since I'm using windows to access a specific image in the directory

`image = PATH + "\\" + "some_image.gif"`

This is where my question lies, this works on windows, but if I remember correctly `"\\"` is for windows and this will not work on other OS? I cannot directly test this myself as I don't have other operating systems or I wouldn't have bothered posting. As far as I can tell from where I've looked this isn't mentioned in the documentation.
If this is indeed the case is there a way around this?

Comment: Just use `/'s`, that will work on every OS

Comment: What's the `os.path.join` there for? If you just pass one thing to `join`, you just get back that one thing; there's nothing to join it to.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you _not_ using `os.path.join` in the `image = ` line? That's exactly where you _do_ need it.

Comment: Good point just reusing code from another program where i was walking over the directories counting files etc. Also, why would i need the .join in the image line? I set up the `PATH` variable then used it in the image line to just easily call the arbitrary path for multiple images, files, etc. Only other way I see to do that is to walk over the directory and then access the images from elements of an array just thought that was easier Also, thank you didn't realize `/'s` would work on any OS, thought it was different for some reason

Comment: The reason you need the `join` is because it abstracts out the whole "should I use \\ or / or can I figure out the right thing for the current platform or …" and just does it right.

Comment: @Skeletor: Also, `/` doesn't actually work on any OS. It _usually_ works on Windows, but there are cases where it doesn't, and you don't want to release a program and then get a bug report the first time someone tries to use it with a long UNC path (without even realizing that's what they're doing) and has no idea how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `'\\'` is just for Windows. You can use `os.sep`, which will be `'\\'` on Windows, `':'` on classic Mac, `'/'` on almost everything else, or whatever is appropriate for the current platform.

You can *usually* get away with using `'/'`. Nobody's likely to be running your program on anything but Windows or Unix. And Windows will accept `'/'` pathnames in *most* cases. But there are many Windows command-line tools that will confuse your path for a flag if it starts with `/`, and some even if you have a `/` in the middle, and if you're using `\\.\` paths, a `/` is treated like a regular character rather than a separator, and so on. So you're better off not doing that.

The simple thing to do is just use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
image = os.path.join(PATH, "some_image.gif")
```

---

As a side note, in your first line, you're already using `join`—but you don't need it there:

```
PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))
```

It's perfectly legal to call `join` with only one argument like this, but also perfectly useless; you just join the one thing with nothing; you will get back exactly what you passed in. Just do this:

```
PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

---

One last thing: If you're on Python 3.4+, you may want to consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os.path`:

```
PATH = Path(sys.argv[0]).parent.resolve()
image = PATH / "some_image.gif"
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer that cleared up a lot of things I was confused about.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of `"\\"`:

```
os.path.join(PATH, "some_image.gif")
```

The function will join intelligently the different parts of the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))
image = os.path.join(PATH, "some_image.gif")
```

[os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will intelligently join the arguments using [os.sep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep) which uses the OS file separator for you.